# Modelling an open-drain inverter in MultiSim

Tags: inverter, multisim, open-drain

I want to model the [SN74LVC1G06](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74lvc1g06) (it's an open-drain inverter) in MultiSim, specifically the rise and fall time specifications.

The existing inverter model in Multisim just has rising and falling propagation delays, which doesn't help my case.
Could anyone suggest how I can model this part in MultiSim?

Comment: The rise time of an open-collector or open drain output will depend on the pull-up resistor and load on the output.

Answer (score 1):

How about modeling the open-drain inverter as a combination of a (normal) non-inverting buffer driving an n-channel MOSFET?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkDAJe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This basically mimics what's going on within the open drain inverter!